# Xamarin Android Screen Orientation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I'm programming a WebView application for android (blank Xamarin project / Visual Studio 2022). I added this line so the WebView will not reload on orientation change:

`[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]`

This works on the Pixel 5 - API 30 (Android 11.0) Emulator (Debug), but when I install it as APK (Release) on my Galaxy Note 20 the application just shows blank white screen.

Without the:

`ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)`

The application works just fine, but keep reloading on orientation change.

I'm expecting the application will not reload on orientation change and return the user to the homepage which is called via: `webView.LoadUrl("url");` and remain on the current web page.

Comment: "*I'm expecting ..."* - you have to put any needed code into `OnConfigurationChanged`. That's why Android's default (without `ConfigurationChanged = ...`) is to restart the app. It has no way of knowing what your app needs, when there is a configuration change. You suppressed it, so you are responsible for anything that needs to be done. Why it works okay in one situation but not another, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added `public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig); }` but nothing changed, the application still shows blank white screen on boot. Yeah I can't understand either why it works on the emulator and not on the actual smartphone.

Comment: Nothing changed, because you didn't tell it to do anything different. Perhaps WebView on Galaxy Note 20 needs to be told to redraw itself, after a rotation. Is this Xamarin.Forms (cross-platformUI, being run on Android), or Xamarin.Android (native Android API using c#)? Either way, whatever you did to show the webview in the first place, do it again after calling `base.OnC...(...);`. I don't know whether you need to do `webView.LoadUrl("url");`, or whether you need to create the entire page again `somevariablenamehere = new YourPageNameHere();` Experiment.

Comment: Thank you very much @ToolmakerSteve for taking the time to help, I did solved it and added the answer. I hope it will help other people facing this. This is Xamarin, not Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by changing on Release:

- "Linking" to "None" on Android Options
- unchecking "Define TRACE constant" on Build

Removing

```
ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
```

added this to OnCreate():

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) 
{
     webView.LoadUrl("url");
}
```

and these:

```
protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    webView.SaveState(outState);
    base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    webView.RestoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why those 3 bullet points? That is going to be a very large aab/apk when built for release. You should always use SDK and User assemblies for a release build.

Comment: You are correct about "Optimizing Code" (reducing from 75MB to 20MB), but with the other two the application just don't work.

Comment: What is the problem with the TRACE constant? I doubt I've ever unchecked it. Do you have any other strange settings in your Release build?